# Autocomplete combobox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete

I have a problem with autocompete combobox using jquery. Here I'm dynamically adding the new combobox. There is a add button functionality to add the combobox dynamically.

My autocomplete is working fine in all comboboxes but the problem is whenever I trigger an event on any combobox, the action is happening on the last combobox. There is a problem with comboboxes indexes. I have written the widget code inside the function setDamagedVehicle(status) so that I can track the each and every combobox but it's not working. Whenever I click on add button the function setDamagedVehicle(status) is called and is working fine but the juery code is executing only on the last status value. Please help me how to track the each and every combobox. I'm not able to save the correct values in the hidden variables. Here I am using the struts framework.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function setDamagedVehicle(status){
      //Here I have written the at widget code so that I can track each and every combobox using the status value.            
     (function( $ ) {
         $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
              _create: function() {
                this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                  .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                  .insertAfter( this.element );

                this.element.hide();
                this._createAutocomplete();
                this._createShowAllButton();
              },

             _createAutocomplete: function() {
                    // some statements
                    this._on( this.input, {
                    autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger( "select", event, {
                    item: ui.item.option
                    });
                    var selectedObject = ui.item.value;
                    var selectedObjectCode = ui.item.option.value;
                    $( "#vehicleObjectCodeText-"+status ).val(selectedObjectCode);                        
                    $( "#objectValueText-"+status ).val(selectedObject.trim());                         
                    var selectBox = document.getElementById('claimObjectCombo-'+status);

               // saving selected item in form through hidden selectedIndexText field
               for(var i = 0, j = selectBox.options.length; i < j; ++i) {
                    if(selectBox.options[i].innerHTML === selectedObject) {
                          $( "#selectedIndexText-"+status).val(i);
                           break;
                          }
                    }
              },

            });

          },   /* _createAutocomplete close */
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
          // fine
       },
     _source: function( request, response ) {
          //fine
       },
     _destroy: function() {
          // fine
      }
     });     /* widget close */
    })( jQuery );   /* function close */ 

}
 $(function() {
       $( ".objectComboBox" ).combobox();
 });
</script>

<logic:iterate collection="${claimNotificationForm.vehicles}" id="vehicle" property="vehicles" indexId="vehicleIndex">
<td class="tiivis">
   <div class="ui-widget">
     <!-- hidden element with vehicleObjectValue is set to save selected vehicle code before form submit -->
    <html:hidden property="vehicleObjectValue[${vehicleIndex}]" styleId="objectValueText-${vehicleIndex}"/>
    <!-- hidden element with selectedIndex is set to save selected vehicle index before form submit -->
     <html:hidden property="selectedIndex[${vehicleIndex}]" styleId="selectedIndexText-${vehicleIndex}"/>
     <html:hidden property="vehicleObject[${vehicleIndex}]" styleId="vehicleObjectCodeText-${vehicleIndex}"/>
    <html:select  property="vehicleObject[${vehicleIndex}]" styleId="claimObjectCombo-${vehicleIndex}" styleClass="objectComboBox" onkeypress="enterStopper(event);">
    <!-- values are getting from other system and this is working fine -->
    <vehicles:optionsCollection property="objectTypes"  sort="true"    chooseKey="000" chooseResourceKey="page.claim.search.object.name"/>
    </html:select>
  </div>    
 </td>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         setDamagedVehicle(${vehicleIndex});
</script>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Hi Guys need some help

Comment: can you help please.. @VonC